# MYSQL select all children (and their children) based upon root parent

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I have a table setupup as follows (simplified of course)

```
code |  descx           | parentcode    | levelx
-----+------------------+---------------+--------
FF00 |  Fruit           | ROOT          | 0
VV00 |  Veggies         | ROOT          | 0
F001 |  Citrus Fruits   | FF00          | 1
V001 |  Roots           | VV00          | 1
F002 |  Oranges         | F001          | 2
F003 |  Tangerine       | F001          | 2
F004 |  Grapefruit      | F001          | 2
F005 |  Lemon           | F001          | 2
V002 |  Carrot          | V001          | 2
V003 |  Beetroot        | V001          | 2
V004 |  Radish          | V001          | 2
F101 |  Big Orange      | F002          | 3
F103 |  Small Orange    | F003          | 3
```

What I would like to achieve is select all nodes related to Fruit so I end up with a data set that looks like

```
code |  descx           | parentcode    | levelx
-----+------------------+---------------+--------
FF00 |  Fruit           | ROOT          | 0
F001 |  Citrus Fruits   | FF00          | 1
F002 |  Oranges         | F001          | 2
F003 |  Tangerine       | F001          | 2
F004 |  Grapefruit      | F001          | 2
F005 |  Lemon           | F001          | 2
F101 |  Big Orange      | F002          | 3
F103 |  Small Orange    | F003          | 3
```

I tried the following MYSQL but this just pulled out my whole table

```
select t.* from 
(
    SELECT 
        c.code, 
        c.descx, 
        c.parentcode,
        c.levelx,
    FROM 
        food c
   left join
     food p
   on
    c.parentcode = p.code
    WHERE 
        c.code = 'FF00'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        child.code, 
        child.descx, 
        child.parentcode,
        child.levelx,
        child.flags
    FROM 
        food child
    INNER JOIN 
        food parent
    ON 
        child.parentcode = parent.code
) as t
```

any advise?

Comment: By convention, 'ROOT' parents (i.e. orphans) are NULL. Beyond that, you will have noticed that MySQL (still) has no innate capacity for recursion. Choices include: joining the table to itself as often as could be required, constructing a sproc, handling the logic at the application level (e.g. PHP), or switching to an alternative model (e.g. nested set)

Comment: @Strawberry - I did try to join the table to itself and it just didn't work. Could you maybe provide me of an example with my code above on how to achieve?

Comment: If you provide a sqlfiddle, I might think about it!

Comment: @Strawberry - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf94ce/4